# How to import metadata file from identity provider?

Tags: passport.js, saml

I am setting up SSO for my SaaS product to integrate with the users directory of one of my customers.
The customer provided a metadata file and a certificate.
I am using Express, PassportJS, and passport-saml.

Looking at the documentation here:
http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-saml/

I see that there are config parameters. I was wondering if the idea is to import those definitions from the metadata provided to me by the identity provider somehow.

Also, I am not clear as to why there is a section called generateServiceProviderMetadata? why would the service provider need to generate metadata file? isn't that something that is set only once?

for the cert I am assuming that I need to import it as such:

```
const someStrategy = new SamlStrategy(
  {
    path: '/login/callback',
    entryPoint: 'https://some.url.com',
    issuer: 'passport-saml',
    privateCert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.pem', 'utf-8')
  },
```

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Comment: yes. actually this site - https://www.xecurify.com/ was very helpful in providing a test mechanism to work with. they have pretty detailed documentation. I am still not clear what is the use of generateServiceProviderMetadata though